# Delete lines if column in file1 falls within falls within range declared in two columns in other file

Tags: excel, bash, awk

I have been working on this issue for a while, and surprisingly have not found much help by searching. 
I have two tab-delimited files, one which looks like this:

file 1

```
#CHROM          POS ..~100 columns...
ref|NC_001133|  250...
ref|NC_001133|  500...
ref|NC_001133|  802...
ref|NC_001133|  15052...
ref|NC_001133|  23560...
ref|NC_001133|  28800...
```

and another that looks like this:

file 2

```
#CHROM          POS1 POS2       
ref|NC_001133|  1    801
ref|NC_001133|  1    62
ref|NC_001133|  337  801
ref|NC_001133|  63   336
ref|NC_001133|  1807 2169
ref|NC_001133|  13363 13743
ref|NC_001133|  24000 27968
```

What I want is to delete the rows in file1 that fall within the range specified by POS1 and POS2. So my expected output would be:

expected output:

```
#CHROM POS ..~100 columns...
ref|NC_001133| 802...
ref|NC_001133| 15052...
ref|NC_001133| 23560...
ref|NC_001133| 28800...
```

I have tried several codes, including this one, which produces a file with nothing:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ range[$1,$2,$3]; next } FNR==1{for(x in range) {split(x, check, SUBSEP); if($1==check[1] && $2>=check[2] && $2<=check[3]) print $0,"\t", "x"}}' todeleteshort.txt short_test.txt > test_short_output.txt
```

I tried to modify the code used on this page: 
[AWK: extract lines if column in file 1 falls within a range declared in two columns in other file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526131/awk-extract-lines-if-column-in-file-1-falls-within-a-range-declared-in-two-colu)

But I fail to delete the lines I don't want while keeping the lines I do want.

I don't care what language as long as it can be run from the command line.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    NR  == 1  {next}          # file2 header
    FNR == 1  {print; next}   # file1 header
    FNR == NR {min[FNR]=$2; max[FNR]=$3; next}
    {
        for (key in min)
            if (min[key] <= $2 && $2 <= max[key])
                next
        print
    }
' file2 file1
```

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as karakfa's, but IMO more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use sed instead, because the delete lines are inclusive of the range bounds it makes it very easy.

You can tell sed to perform an action fro a range of lines for example sed '10,20d;25,35d' will perform the "d" or delete command for lines 10 through 20, and again for lines 25 through 35.

Note you can use newlines instead of ; for each individual command. This is what we will here for simplicity since your data in file2 is already line based.

So all you need to do is turn those POS1, POS2 columns in file2 into a list of commands like above, and then run sed using the command you created. If it is very long, you could generate a sed script file from file2 and execute it. Something like this

```
# build the command that will be run by sed.
typeset sed_cmd=$(sed '1d' file2 | awk '{print $2","$3"d"}')

# Now execute the sed command you constructed on file1.
sed "$cmd" file1 > results_file

# If you want sed to modify the input file1 in place use the -i option.
sed -i "$cmd" file1
```

Comment: Thank you! I must admit that I don't quite understand how sed works, but this worked for what I needed to accomplish. Much appreciated!

Comment: @hollygene don't feel bad. It takes a bit before sed stops feeling like this thing of magic :) but it is very powerful tool for this sort of thing, so is awk :) and together they are a formidable. if you are ever interested in learning more about them this is a good resource http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR && NR>1 {p1[NR]=$2; p2[NR]=$3; count=NR; next}
       FNR>1{for(i=2;i<=count;i++) if($2>=p1[i] && $2<=p2[i]) next} 
       NR>1' file2 file1

#CHROM          POS ..~100 columns...
ref|NC_001133|  802
ref|NC_001133|  15052
ref|NC_001133|  23560
ref|NC_001133|  28800
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works quite well, although I must admit I don't quite understand it (I'm rather new to linux in general).